# Third Party app crashes and gives UIAutomation not connected error, how do you fix this?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I'm running an automation test that starts up a third party application on an android device. By running this:

```
@Given("^I open app")
    public void launchThirdParty() throws Exception {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("adb -s " + AndroidDevice.deviceName + " shell am start -n " +
                "app.integration/.ui.MainActivity");
```

This will open the application but then crashes after 50 seconds and this error pops up on my logs:

```
E/UiDevice: Exceuting watcher: CRASH2
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
        at android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:971)
        at android.app.UiAutomation.waitForIdle(UiAutomation.java:577)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiAutomatorBridge.waitForIdle(UiAutomatorBridge.java:96)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiAutomatorBridge.waitForIdle(UiAutomatorBridge.java:91)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.QueryController.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(QueryController.java:143)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.QueryController.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(QueryController.java:138)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(UiObject.java:168)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.waitForExists(UiObject.java:852)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.exists(UiObject.java:903)
        at com.android.uiautomator.common.UiWatchers$4.checkForCondition(UiWatchers.java:107)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.runWatchers(UiDevice.java:557)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(UiObject.java:173)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.waitForExists(UiObject.java:852)
        at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject.exists(UiObject.java:903)
        at io.appium.android.bootstrap.utils.TheWatchers.isDialogPresent(TheWatchers.java:51)
        at io.appium.android.bootstrap.utils.TheWatchers.check(TheWatchers.java:36)
        at io.appium.android.bootstrap.SocketServer$1.run(SocketServer.java:140)
        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

I've looked up on the error and there doesn't seem to be much information on this or any quick fixes or workarounds, can someone help me in resolving this issue and making sure that this app doesn't crash?

Comment: Did you add **DesiredCapabilities** and initialize **AppiumDriver** in your code?

Comment: Yes both are set, I'm able to run through other apps installed on the android device but now this has happened only when testing on a third party app

Comment: what do you mean by third party app?

Comment: So i'm testing on my own applications which have been directly installed on the device for a purpose but this application will be integrated into these apps later down the line but the app is from a different source. In terms of automation this issue shouldn't arise by running this but I can't understand why it does

Comment: How did you try to run third party app? Do you use DesiredCapabilities and AppiumDriver for third party app too?

Comment: Yeah all the same as going through the other apps, I don't know is this an issue with appium driver as there was a suggestion to use adbkit online but I don't want to go to that approach if there's a fix on using appiumdriver